# HTML ul li, remove space between dots and text without padding, margin, or text-indent properties

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, nsattributedstring

I have to display `<blockquote>` tag in iOS application in attributed string. iOS dont know this tag and displays it as usual text. I try to achieve tab effect for blockquotes by using  list, I use `list-style-type: none` to remove the dots, but the problem is that space between text and dot is very big. Also the problem is that NSAttributedString dont understand padding, margin, or text-indent properties. So my question is, is this possible to remove the extra space, but not using padding, margin, or text-indent properties?
Any help is appreciate.

Upd: here what I tried

```
newMessage.content_html.replacingOccurrences(of: "<blockquote>", with: "<ul style=\"list-style-type: none;\"><li><i style=\"color:rgb(220,220,200);\"><blockquote>").replacingOccurrences(of: "</blockquote>", with: "</blockquote></i></li></ul>")
```

Comment: show you code please

Comment: @לבני מלכה updated question.

Comment: If the issue is that that the result needs to look just like a blockquote in an ordinary browser, blockquotes have the same margins as uls, so it sounds like it's working as designed. If not, can you post a screenshot of the current solution? Maybe I'm missing something, because I don't have an iPhone.

Comment: the problem is that NSAttributedString dont understand padding, margin, or text-indent properties. I have to display it it iOS UITextView.